# Python - dropping rows based on multiple filters

Tags: python, pandas

quick question on how to remove rows that have multiple blanks opposed to one at a time?

for example:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | X | X |  |
| X | X | X | X |
| X |  |  |  |
| X | X |  |  |
| X | X | X | X |
| X | X | X | X |
| X |  |  |  |

My DataFrame has 20k entries so manually parsing it out is not possible. I would like to write a script that basically does something similar to an excel script that basically says:

If 2,3 and 4 are empty, drop row

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

This will drop all rows which have 3 or more NAs

Comment: Empty is likely `''` so I'd `mask` first.  `df.where(df.astype(bool)).dropna(thresh=2)`

Answer (score 1):

#### boolean mask

```
df[(~df.astype(bool)).sum(axis=1).le(2)]

   1  2  3  4
0  X  X  X   
1  X  X  X  X
3  X  X      
4  X  X  X  X
5  X  X  X  X
```